# Parse date range using daterangeparser library

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to parse a date range using the [`daterangeparser` package](http://daterangeparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) in Python3.x but I am unable to do it properly. Any help is much appreciated,

My code,

```
from daterangeparser import parse
c = '2018-03-10 - 2018-06-15'
s, e = parse(c)
print(s, e)
```

And the error is,

```
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd (at char 7), (line:1, col:8)
```

Comment: I think the problem may be that it expects the dash character to be the separator between two dates, not the day/month/year separator within a date.  Maybe try slashes instead of dashes?

Comment: The parser falls over `2018-03-`, so presumably it expected the first dash to be the range delimiter.

Comment: The parser doesn't support **any** ISO8601 strings, including these dates. They support human-style strings only.

Comment: I also see that the documentation claims to support "most date formats", but all the examples use month names, i.e. `10 Jan 2001` instead of `1-10-2001`.  I guess this actually makes sense, as a wholly numeric date could be ambiguous -- day-month-year (european style), or month-day-year (american style).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `daterangeparser` library only supports specific string formatting.

Looking at the [documentation](https://daterangeparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), this is one way which is likely to work:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from daterangeparser import parse

c = '2018-03-10 - 2018-06-15'

test = ' - '.join([dt.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d %b %Y') for i in c.split(' - ')])
# '10 Mar 2018 - 15 Jun 2018'    

res = parse(test)
```

However, for what you are looking to do it seems like you may not need to use `daterangeparser`.

Comment: If you're using `strptime` to parse the dates, what is the point of using `daterangeparser` at all?